# Replace Html.EditorFor for Bootstrap Toggle

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am using `Html.EditorFor` in conjunction with a `bool?` field and wonder if it is possible to replace this with Bootstrap Toggle.

I have tried the following:

```
ViewBag.News = Convert.ToBoolean(model.News) ? "Yes" : "No";

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.News)
<input name="news" type="checkbox" value="@ViewBag.News" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="No" data-on="Yes" data-onstyle="success" />
```

It appears that the `value` field is being ignored, and looking at examples on `http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/` the use of value is nowhere to be seen, which is strange as its a checkbox initially.

Any ideas on how to bind the model data to a Bootstrap Data-Toggle componenet would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 1 represents a checked field the below should work:

```
<input name="news" type="checkbox" @(ViewBag.News == "Yes" ? "checked" : "")
             data-toggle="toggle" data-off="No" data-on="Yes" data-onstyle="success"/>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked with a little tweak <input name="news" type="checkbox" @(ViewBag.News == "Yes" ? "checked" : "") data-toggle="toggle" data-off="No" data-on="Yes" data-onstyle="success"/>`

Answer (score 2):

For MVC 5 this seems to work:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsPayed, 
new { htmlAttributes = 
new { data_toggle = "toggle", data_on = "Payed", data_off = "Not payed", data_onstyle = "success", data_offstyle = "danger", type = "checkbox" } })
```

Use _ instead of - in the htmlAttributes and they pass and are converted to -.
(IsPayed is a boolean in the model)